# Super-type/Sub-type in Software Engineering

Tags: erd

Is super-type and subtype relation exists between two entities in (ERD)software Engineering. Actually I was confused it with DBMS, because as I know that in Data Base this relation exists between two or more entities (ERD).

Comment: what is your question exactly?  it is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't a specific programming problem. [programmers.se] might be a better fit, but the question probably needs to be clarified a bit first.

Answer (score 1):

In Information Engineering Methodology, the concept of type/subtype exists. It is represented in ERD as in this example:

[image]

In database there are different ways to implement the type/subtype concept for example:

1. You could have a table with a discriminating column and include all unique columns of the 2 types. You'd have to specify subtype columns as Null in this case because they are expected to be mutually exclusive in any one given row. An example of a discriminating column for the above example may be: IsStudent (Yes/No).
2. You could have a base type table with 1-1 optional association (relationship) to each sub type.

Each of the above approaches have its own benefits and drawbacks.